# UI Issue with kal calendar for ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have UI issue with Kal Calendar for iPad. On the iPad there is an empty space but on the iPhone it's fine. How can i get it to fit in the frame on the iPad?

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    [kal.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    [kal.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,768 ,1004)];

}
```

I tried to use the code listed above but it did not work for me!

[image]

Comment: try putting a break point and debug your code to check if that line of code is reached or not.

Comment: @Rajeel UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is working properly!....

Comment: UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is working properly..!  but frame is same do any one know why its happening! any advice! please!

Comment: Very likly the author didn't have the iPad in mind and there for the buttons have a fixed size

Comment: @ vikingosegundo So! is there any alternative Way for ipad!

Comment: yeah: branch Kal and fix that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in KalGridView.m you'll find this.

```
const CGSize kTileSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

I'd change the code to a property where you can set the frame dynamically to the idiom and/or orientation.

in KalGridView.m

```
 const CGSize kTileSize = { 109.0f, 109.0f };
```

and in KalView.m

```
- (void)addSubviewsToHeaderView:(UIView *)headerView

  …

  for (CGFloat xOffset = 0.f; xOffset < headerView.width; xOffset += 109.f, i = (i+1)%7) {
    CGRect weekdayFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 30.f, 109.f, kHeaderHeight - 29.f);
    UILabel *weekdayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:weekdayFrame];
    weekdayLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    weekdayLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.f];
    weekdayLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    weekdayLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3f green:0.3f blue:0.3f alpha:1.f];
    weekdayLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    weekdayLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.f, 1.f);
    weekdayLabel.text = [weekdayNames objectAtIndex:i];
    [headerView addSubview:weekdayLabel];
    [weekdayLabel release];
  }
}
```

results in:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: FYI: If you decide to make the `const kTileSize` mutable, there are `extern`'s throughout Kal that reference the kTileSize.  One way to resolve this is to create a singleton with the tileSize property which will allow access throughout Kal but also allow you to change the size in the ViewController's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: @Vikingosegundo can we handle orientation in KAL calendar?

Comment: @Prabh be aware, that I am not the author of KAL. there is no technical reason, why it shouldn't be possible. but you might have to alter the code.

Comment: They say, "You would typically add one primary view controller such as a UINavigationController, UITabBarController or a generic UIViewController to your UIWindow. For example, this is done by calling:

[myWindow addSubview:primaryViewController.view];

If you add an additional view controller's UIView property to UIWindow (at the same level as your primary view controller) via the following:

[myWindow addSubview:anotherController.view];

this additional view controller will not receive rotation events and will never rotate. Only the first view controller added to UIWindow will rotate.

Comment: this has resolved the problem for iPad but, not helpful for universal app. Is there any way so i can put these effort for universal app also?