# Kal Calendar for Universal App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app, kal

I am updating my app to a universal app but there is something wrong with the Kal Calendar:

[image]

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835373/ui-issue-with-kal-calendar-for-ipad) it says I should change:

```
const CGSize kTileSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

to

```
const CGSize kTileSize = { 109.0f, 109.0f };
```

but then it looks great on iPad but not iPhone. How can I make the Kal Calendar for both iPhone and iPad?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a constant in this case - you will have to define the value at runtime.

Initialize `kTileSize` as an ivar of the class where it is defined.

And then in constructor of that class do someting like:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    kTileSize = {109.0f, 109.0f};
}
else
{
    kTileSize = {46.f, 44.f}; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have done a modification for Kal calendar and it has all the functionalities as below.

1. UI changes for the Universal application
2. UI for orientation changes

Please find it here.... https://github.com/maheshidesilva/KalExt